# RethinkDB timestamp filtering issue

Tags: timestamp, rethinkdb

I want to sort information in database by periods of time it was added. I have such structure of item:

[image]

For example i'm need to get count of items in this table for period from 12:30 to 12:31.

Can you please help me with ReQL command for this?

Comment: please post your data structure as text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your timestamp is sadly not in ISO8601 format (`2018-12-22T12:35:40.289028Z`) and therefore you cannot use the rethink `.during` method. But you can fall back to string comparison:

```
r.db("test").table("sample").filter(function(doc){
    return doc("Message")("timestamp").gt("2018-12-22 12:30:00.000000")
      .and(doc("Message")("timestamp").lt("2018-12-22 12:31:00.000000"))
}).count()
```

Comment: Thank you! If I could +1 you, i'd did it, but system tells me that i'm not allowed to do that. So i do this comment instead.

Comment: You can still accept the answer :) but anyway you're welcome  ;)